Как сделать чтоб получать все фотографии из альбома aiogram 3?
Тут я уже использовал MiddleWare, мне надо чтоб получить каждое фото из альбома
 @start_router.message(GetMessage.text)
    async def text(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
        mes_id = ID()
        data = await state.get_data()
        photo = message.photo
        media_id = message.media_group_id
        photos = data.get('photos', [])
        photos.append(photo[-1].file_id)
        await state.update_data(photos=photos)
        await message.answer(f"Загружено {len(photos)}")
        print(photos)

